# Maximizing plots in R Shiny bs4Dash

Tags: r, shiny, adminlte, wordcloud2, bs4dash

I have looked online everywhere to no avail. I cannot seem to get these plots to maximize their heights and widths to full window size upon maximizing the boxes. It is a requirement that I use `bs4Dash`. I looked at [this post](https://github.com/RinteRface/bs4Dash/issues/146) but the provided solutions did not seem to work for me. What am I missing?

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(circlepackeR) # devtools::install_github("jeromefroe/circlepackeR")
library(wordcloud2) # devtools::install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2")
library(plotly)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(id="histbox", 
          title = "hist box", 
          plotOutput("plot1", 
                     height = 250),
          maximizable = T),
      
      box(id = "circlebox", title="circle box", 
          circlepackeR::circlepackeROutput("circles"), maximizable = T)
      
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(id="wordlcoudbox", 
          title = "wordcloud box", 
          wordcloud2::wordcloud2Output("cloud"), 
          maximizable = T),
      
      box(id = "plotlybox",
          title = "plotly box", 
          plotly::plotlyOutput("plotlyplot"), 
          maximizable = T))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(10)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  
  output$plotlyplot <- renderPlotly(
    plot1 <- plot_ly(
      type = 'scatter',
      mode = 'markers')
  )
  
  
  
  hierarchical_list <- list(name = "World",
                            children = list(
                              list(name = "North America",
                                   children = list(
                                     list(name = "United States", size = 308865000),
                                     list(name = "Mexico", size = 107550697),
                                     list(name = "Canada", size = 34033000))),
                              list(name = "South America", 
                                   children = list(
                                     list(name = "Brazil", size = 192612000),
                                     list(name = "Colombia", size = 45349000),
                                     list(name = "Argentina", size = 40134425))),
                              list(name = "Europe",  
                                   children = list(
                                     list(name = "Germany", size = 81757600),
                                     list(name = "France", size = 65447374),
                                     list(name = "United Kingdom", size = 62041708))),
                              list(name = "Africa",  
                                   children = list(
                                     list(name = "Nigeria", size = 154729000),
                                     list(name = "Ethiopia", size = 79221000),
                                     list(name = "Egypt", size = 77979000))),
                              list(name = "Asia",  
                                   children = list(
                                     list(name = "China", size = 1336335000),
                                     list(name = "India", size = 1178225000),
                                     list(name = "Indonesia", size = 231369500)))
                            )
  )
  
  output$cloud <- wordcloud2::renderWordcloud2(wordcloud2(demoFreq, 
                                                          minRotation = -pi/6, 
                                                          maxRotation = -pi/6, 
                                                          minSize = 10,
                                                          rotateRatio = 1))
  
  output$circles <- circlepackeR::renderCirclepackeR(circlepackeR(hierarchical_list))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5):

As @yeahman269 mentioned, @ismirsehregal's solution wasn't working for me.

I've created a different solution that does work for me using a combination of @ismirsehregal's solution in this current post and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72742583/scalability-of-plots-within-bs4dashbox-when-maximizable-true-in-r-shiny) post.

**Importantly**, the solution I've created is functional, meaning that you only have to insert a single line per plot into the server.

Please find a minimally reproducible example below. The most important part is the is the `add_plot_maximize_observer` function. Hopefully this works for you as it worked for me!

```r
# Plot resizing example

library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(shinyjs)
library(plotly)

#' Add a box maximization observer to automatically resize a plot in that box.
#'
#' @param input The input of a shiny app session.
#' @param box_id The shiny ID of the box to observe.
#' @param plot_name The shiny ID of the plot to resize.
#' @param non_max_height The height that the graph should be when the box is
#'   not maximized. Defaults to "400px".
add_plot_maximize_observer <- function(input,
                                       box_id,
                                       plot_name,
                                       non_max_height = "400px") {
  observeEvent(input[[box_id]]$maximized, {
    plot_height <- if (input[[box_id]]$maximized) {
      "100%"
    } else {
      non_max_height
    }
    
    js_call <- sprintf(
      "
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('#%s').css('height', '%s');
      }, 300)
      $('#%s').trigger('resize');
      ",
      plot_name,
      plot_height,
      plot_name
    )
    shinyjs::runjs(js_call)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(
                      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                      box(
                        id = "graph_box",
                        maximizable = TRUE,
                        collapsible = FALSE,
                        width = 12,
                        plotly::plotlyOutput("mpg_wt")
                      )
                    ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mpg_wt <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    plotly::plot_ly(
      mtcars,
      x = ~ wt,
      y = ~ mpg,
      type = "scatter",
      mode = "markers"
    )
  })
  
  add_plot_maximize_observer(input, "graph_box", "mpg_wt")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: your function works perfectly! However how would this work for a bs4TabCard with tabPanel? Cause entering the id of tabPanel doesnt work cause box_id is a different id. I tried to change box_id with  tabPanel_id or tabsetPanel_id  (see [here](https://rinterface.github.io/bs4Dash/reference/insertTab.html)) in the function but doesnt work. Also working with the id of [bs4TabCard](https://rinterface.github.io/bs4Dash/reference/tabBox.html) doesnt work and get an error `Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: @H. berg -- The solution is that the state of a `tabBox` (`bs4TabCard` alias) isn't stored in its `input` name. Instead, given a `tabBox` with an `id = "my_tabs"`, you can access the state of the `tabBox` maximization using `osbserveEvent(input$my_tabs_box$maximized, {...})`. The key part of this is adding the `_box` to the end of your box `id`. See [here](https://rinterface.github.io/bs4Dash/reference/tabBox.html#:~:text=items.%20See%20example.-,Note,-User%20will%20access) for the rinterface Bootstrap documentation that explains this.

Comment: Did you try this yourself too? Cause at my side it doesnt work. Would be great If you can check it!

Answer (score 2):

The following is not a fully working answer, but I'll share it anyway:

We can use `library(shinyjs)` to dynamically change CSS style properties. Please see this [related article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).

However, `wordcloud2` and `circlepackeR` don't react on their `height` and `width` arguments as expected - only the margins change but the charts remain the same size (no matter where those arguments are changed).

The `base` plot get's resized only after maximizing it's box twice.

The `plotly` chart works fine.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(circlepackeR) # devtools::install_github("jeromefroe/circlepackeR")
library(wordcloud2) # devtools::install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2")
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(id="histbox", 
          title = "hist box", 
          plotOutput("plot1", width = "100%"),
          maximizable = T),
      box(id = "circlebox", title="circle box", 
          circlepackeR::circlepackeROutput("circles"), # , width = "2000px", height = "2000px" # hopeless, only adds space - plot remains the same size
          maximizable = T)
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(id="wordlcoudbox", 
          title = "wordcloud box", 
          wordcloud2::wordcloud2Output("cloud"), # , width = "2000px", height = "2000px" # hopeless, only adds space - cloud remains the same size
          maximizable = T),
      box(id = "plotlybox",
          title = "plotly box", 
          plotly::plotlyOutput("plotlyplot"), 
          maximizable = T))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(10)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotlyplot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  })
  
  hierarchical_list <- list(name = "World",
                            children = list(
                              list(name = "North America",
                                   children = list(
                                     list(name = "United States", size = 308865000),
                                     list(name = "Mexico", size = 107550697),
                                     list(name = "Canada", size = 34033000))),
                              list(name = "South America", 
                                   children = list(
                                     list(name = "Brazil", size = 192612000),
                                     list(name = "Colombia", size = 45349000),
                                     list(name = "Argentina", size = 40134425))),
                              list(name = "Europe",  
                                   children = list(
                                     list(name = "Germany", size = 81757600),
                                     list(name = "France", size = 65447374),
                                     list(name = "United Kingdom", size = 62041708))),
                              list(name = "Africa",  
                                   children = list(
                                     list(name = "Nigeria", size = 154729000),
                                     list(name = "Ethiopia", size = 79221000),
                                     list(name = "Egypt", size = 77979000))),
                              list(name = "Asia",  
                                   children = list(
                                     list(name = "China", size = 1336335000),
                                     list(name = "India", size = 1178225000),
                                     list(name = "Indonesia", size = 231369500)))
                            )
  )
  
  output$cloud <- wordcloud2::renderWordcloud2(wordcloud2(demoFreq,
                                                          minRotation = -pi/6, 
                                                          maxRotation = -pi/6, 
                                                          minSize = 10,
                                                          rotateRatio = 1))
  
  output$circles <- circlepackeR::renderCirclepackeR(circlepackeR(hierarchical_list))
  
  observeEvent(input$histbox$maximized, {
    if(input$histbox$maximized){
      # runjs('document.getElementById("histbox").style.setProperty("background-color", "green", "important");')
      runjs('var plot1 = document.querySelector("#plot1 > img")
            plot1.style.setProperty("height", "90vh", "important");
            plot1.style.setProperty("width", "100%", "important");')
    } else {
      runjs('var plot1 = document.querySelector("#plot1 > img")
            plot1.style.setProperty("height", "400px", "important");
            plot1.style.setProperty("width", "100%", "important");')
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plotlybox$maximized, {
    if(input$plotlybox$maximized){
      # runjs('document.getElementById("plotlybox").style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important");')
      runjs('var plotlyplot = document.querySelector("#plotlyplot");
            plotlyplot.style.setProperty("height", "90vh", "important");
            plotlyplot.style.setProperty("width", "100%", "important");')
    } else {
      runjs('var plotlyplot = document.querySelector("#plotlyplot");
            plotlyplot.style.setProperty("height", "400px", "important");
            plotlyplot.style.setProperty("width", "100%", "important");')
    }
  })
  

# not working -------------------------------------------------------------

  # observeEvent(input$circlebox$maximized, {
  #   if(input$circlebox$maximized){
  #     runjs('document.querySelector("#circles").style.setProperty("height", "90vh", "important");
  #           document.querySelector("#circles").style.setProperty("width", "100%", "important");')
  #   } else {
  #     runjs('document.querySelector("#circles").style.setProperty("height", "400px", "important");
  #           document.querySelector("#circles").style.setProperty("width", "100%", "important");')
  #   }
  # })
  # 
  # observeEvent(input$wordlcoudbox$maximized, {
  #   if(input$wordlcoudbox$maximized){
  #     runjs('document.querySelector("#cloud").style.setProperty("height", "90vh", "important");
  #           document.querySelector("#cloud").style.setProperty("width", "100%", "important");')
  #   } else {
  #     runjs('document.querySelector("#cloud").style.setProperty("height", "400px", "important");
  #           document.querySelector("#cloud").style.setProperty("width", "100%", "important");')
  #   }
  # })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

[image: result]

Comment: From my side, none of the graph in @ismirsehregal answer actually resizes, even after maximising twice or more.

Comment: @yeahman269 I added a gif of the result on my system. However, it might be a timing issue on your setup as David Granjon uses `setTimeout` in his solution. For future readers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72742583/scalability-of-plots-within-bs4dashbox-when-maximizable-true-in-r-shiny/73829748#73829748) you can find @yeahman269's related question.